# Difference grammar between <ListBox.ItemsSource> and ItemsSource in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xpath

In xaml, there are two styles:

Style 1:

```
<ListBox Width="400" Height="300" Background="Honeydew"
**ItemsSource**="{Binding Source={StaticResource InventoryData},
XPath=*[@Stock\=\'out\'] | *[@Number>\=8 or @Number\=3]}">
```

Style 2:

```
  <ListBox Width="400" Height="300" Background="Honeydew">
    **<ListBox.ItemsSource>**
      <Binding Source="{StaticResource InventoryData}"
               XPath="*[@Stock='out'] | *[@Number>=8 or @Number=3]"/>
    </ListBox.ItemsSource>
```

You can notice there are difference **grammar**. Style 2 have **" "** after Source and XPath and Style 1 need escape for **'**/**=**

Does anyone help me understand why style 1 and style 2 have difference grammar?

I hope i describe my question well.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in Style 1 `XPath` is inside a string, so you need `\` for special characters. I gusess that preprocessor needs this to separate `XPath` from its value and then decode the value.

In Style 2 only the value of `XPath` is as a string, so you can use more natural grammar.